# about efficiency of implementing effects with JavaFX or CSS

Tags: java, css, performance, javafx-2, fxml

i'm working on a personal project (which is a game) on JavaFX and i have a question to take your suggestions. As you know JavaFX can parse data from a .fxml file. So my main map (converted from a .jpeg file into a .svg file) is constructed from a fxml file and every country is converted into SVGPath which has the same properties with `Node` or `Shape` so i have to use MouseListener for every country to insert some effects. Moreover, there are 2 ways to implement these effects which are

- I can use FXML-CSS (like `hover` property for every country (in other words for every `Node` or `Shape`)
- I can implement effects in JavaFX with MouseListeners rather than using CSS.

My question is which one is more efficient and reliable. Or if i use both of them will there be a syncronization problem ?.

I hope my question is clear and i will appreciate for every answer. thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there will be performance differences between utilizing css or using the equivalent java code apis, for the situation you outline (implementing a mouse listener versus a hover css pseudo-class), the performance difference would be immaterial.

You do mention effects, but don't really say what effects you are using.  JavaFX 2 only has limited effect capabilites via css (dropshadow and innershadow), so for that version, you need to apply most effects in code anyway.  Regardless, there shouldn't be any real performance difference between applying an effect in code versus css.

The major performance win you can achieve in relation to effect usage is by setting the JavaFX node [cache](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#cacheProperty) and [cacheHint](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#cacheHintProperty) properties appropriately, so that the JavaFX system precalculates the effect and caches it's result rather than recalculating it all the time as a scene is animated.  In JavaFX 2.2, setting of `cache` and `cacheHint` properties can only be done from code (or in your fxml markup), and not from css.

---

For some general background info, the following related questions might be useful:

- [In JavaFX, should I use CSS or setter methods to change properties on my UI Nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14759323/1155209).
- [JavaFX 2 drawing performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506637/javafx-2-drawing-performance)
- [What is the best way to display millions of images in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467719/what-could-be-the-best-way-to-view-millions-of-images-with-java)

Comment: actually i will deal with just simple effects like innershadow, highlight. (for sure if i improve myself i will use more complex effects maybe). on the other hand, thank you for your very helpful answers ! :)