# Switching The Color for a Component in JavaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, colors, user-controls, javafx-2

If I have an instance of a JavaFX object, say an AnchorPane, how do I switch its background/foreground color? I did a quick Google search and it turned up nothing, also by exploring its methods there was nothing obvious like `setColor()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**General Advice**

Anything which takes a [Paint](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/paint/Paint.html) as a parameter will allow you to set a color, as [Color](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html) is derived from Paint.

There are multiple ways to style components, in general, using [css](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) is often preferred as it allows you to style your scene graph declaratively, separate from program logic.  This makes it much easier to modify and update styles when your application switches to maintenance mode.

**Using CSS**

Simple css style application:

```
anchorPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: cornsilk;");
```

In terms of css application, a stylesheet is recommended over a setStyle call like above.  You can see an explanation of different styling applications in JavaFX in the answer to: [In JavaFX, should I use CSS or setter methods to change properties on my UI Nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14757931/in-javafx-should-i-use-css-or-setter-methods-to-change-properties-on-my-ui-node).

An example of applying a stylesheet:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("pane.css").toExternalForm());
myAnchorPane.getStyleClass().add("colored-pane");
```

And a stylesheet which sets the background color of all AnchorPanes:

```
/** `pane.css` in the same directory as your application class **/
.colored-pane { -fx-background-color: cornsilk; }
```

**Using the Java 8 Background API**

Java 8 introduces a new API to programmatically control backgrounds via the [Background](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/layout/Background.html) class.

```
pane.setBackground(
  new BackgroundFill(
    Color.CRIMSON, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY
  )
);
```

Note, backgrounds (whether defined in css or via the Background API) are only applicable to certain kinds of nodes (e.g. Regions, Layouts and Controls).

**Setting Shape Attributes**

A [Shape](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html#fillProperty) defines some properties you can set to change the shape color.  Common shapes are circles, rectangles, paths and text.

The [stroke](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html#strokeProperty):

```
a stroke that is drawn around the outline of a Shape 
using the settings of the specified Paint.
```

The [fill](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html#fillProperty):

```
fill the interior of an Shape using the settings of the Paint context.
```

Fill and stroke samples:

```
// draws a green square with a thick blue border.
Rectangle square = new Rectangle(30, 30, 50, 50);
square.setFill(Color.GREEN);
square.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
square.setStrokeWidth(6);
```

**Canvas GraphicsContext**

A lot of JavaFX is based on a declarative definitions in a scene graph, fxml and css rather than explicit imperative commands like `setColor()`.  By that I mean the order in which you issue commands doesn't make a lot a of difference.  If you want to use a more traditional approach to drawing, by placing the system in a mode where all subsequent commands act on a context which defines current drawing attributes such as fill and stroke styles, use a [Canvas](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html).

```
// paint two blue rectangles on a canvas.
final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(250,250);
GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

gc.setFill(Color.BLUE);
gc.fillRect(75,75,100,100);
gc.fillRect(25,25,30,30);
```

In general though, for many things, the SceneGraph is preferable to work with than a Canvas as you are working at a higher level of abstraction.  The canvas [GraphicsContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html) does have the advantage of a simple, straight-forward API though which is all defined in a single class.  It is also useful for porting code from other systems such as HTML5 canvas to JavaFX.