# How to apply styles to a group of Labels in javafx without css

Tags: css, javafx, label

I have a javaFx VBox named `countVBox` in which a append Labels on the click of a button. Now with css, I can do:

```
.countVBox .label {
  -fx-background-color: #0000ff;
}
```

I want to achieve the same effect - making the label's background colour blue after it is appended, but without using css. Please tell me if it's possible. Thanks. I am using javafx 2.2

Comment: Do you want the same effect in all the Labels ?

Comment: Yes. Just as in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the background of a region (such as a label), using the [`getBackground()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#getBackground--) API.  Once you have a background, there are [methods on the background](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Background.html) which will allow you to manipulate it via code.

In most cases I'd recommend using CSS (in a stylesheet) over manipulating the region background in Java code.

See also:

- [In JavaFX, should I use CSS or setter methods to change properties on my UI Nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14757931/in-javafx-should-i-use-css-or-setter-methods-to-change-properties-on-my-ui-node)